# Positioning isometric game entities with CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, typescript

For a isometric game overworld, I want to have XYZ positioned entities. I've a movement system that is currently this:

```
import type World from '../World';

export default class MovementSystem {
    constructor(private world: World) {
    }

    update() {
        for (let entity of this.world.entities) {
            let mv = entity.movable;
            if (mv != null && (mv.dx != 0 || mv.dy != 0) && entity.htmlElement != null) {
                entity.x += mv.dx;
                entity.y += mv.dy;
                let cancelledDX = false, cancelledDY = false;
                let rect = entity.rectangle;
                for (let entity2 of this.world.entities) {
                    if (entity == entity2) continue;
                    let rect2 = entity.rectangle;
                    if (!cancelledDX && rect.horizontalHitTest(rect2)) {
                        cancelledDX = true;
                        entity.x -= mv.dx;
                    }
                    if (!cancelledDY && rect.verticalHitTest(rect2)) {
                        cancelledDY = true;
                        entity.y -= mv.dy;
                    }
                }
                entity.htmlElement!.style.left = entity.x + 'px';
                entity.htmlElement!.style.top = entity.y + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code for now only implements XY coordinates. I guess at this point now I just need to setup the Z coordinate. There is a `<div/>` element specifically for the game's overworld to contain HTML elements for the game entities:

```
export default class Scene {
    // ...
    overworldContainer: HTMLElement | null = null;
    // ...
}
```

I guess I could use the CSS property `z-index` for rearranging entities position as adequate.

That's what an entity is defined as:

```
export default class Entity {
    htmlElement: HTMLElement | null = null;
    x: number = 0;
    y: number = 0;
    rectWidth: number = 0;
    rectHeight: number = 0;

    constructor() {
    }

    get rectangle(): Rectangle {
        return new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, this.rectWidth, this.rectHeight);
    }

    get movable(): Movable | null {
        return null;
    }

    set movable(v) {
    }
}

export class Character extends Entity {
    private m_movable: Movable | null = new Movable(0, 0);

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    override get movable(): Movable | null {
        return this.m_movable;
    }

    override set movable(v) {
        this.m_movable = v;
    }
}
```

I'd like to know if there is an easy way for rearranging the game entities as they are moved. Is there, like, something on NPM that could help? As you can see, I'm adapting a Entity-Component-System (ECS) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a Z coordinate I turned my movement system into a `MovementAndZOrderingSystem` system. Besides movement, it'll also swap HTML element positions based in the final Y of the entity in the ECS world. I used jQuery to swap element position.

```
for (let entity of this.world.entities) {
    let mv = entity.movable;
    if (mv != null && (mv.dx != 0 || mv.dy != 0) && entity.htmlElement != null) {
        // movement
        // ...
    }
    // Z-ordering
    for (let entity2 of this.world.entities) {
        if (entity.y > entity2.y) {
            $(entity.htmlElement as any).before($(entity2.htmlElement as any));
        }
    }
}
```

If the overworld has higher Z elements, I can use different `<div/>`s as needed in my `scene.overworldContainer`.

Comment: this sounds like a fun project. can you recommend any reading, tutorials etc?

Comment: @WeAreDoomed I mostly use Mozilla's DOM API, CSS and HTML reference, I done quick research on few things (such as `<img/>` cloning) and debugging too. This gameplay part is just starting, I worked more on the start menu UI so far. What I'm wanting to do is a remake of Phantasy Star III, but of course I'll need an artist to replace classic assets by more modern ones! Anyway, it can be tested here: https://matheusdiasdesouzads.github.io/preview/ps3@0.1.1 The source is currently in GitHub too.

Comment: nice! best of luck